# What is the most useless magic item?

Tags: magic

An example of a useless magic item would be a ring of fire detection with a range of touch. But I'm looking for the most absolutely useless magic item but that's still technically magic. This question is regarding Dungeons and Dragons.

Edit: Try to be as creative as possible

Comment: this doesn't sound like a worldbuilding question, this is asking us to brainstorm for you.

Comment: Ah yes, a [peak reddit moment](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/gefwil/dd_dungeon_masters_of_reddit_what_is_the_most/)

Comment: Brainstorming on an unspecified world with unspecified criteria on how to rank the answers. Definitely not a worldbuilding question according to our [help]

Comment: Not accounting what others said, it's about an already existing world setting which has already a myriad of magic items, so it's even more off-topic. If I were you, I'd only take an item which your class don't get any benefit from, and it's as inert as it could be for you!

Answer (score 6):

An enchanted artifact that points the way to the nearest magical item.  Naturally it only ever points to itself.

Answer (score 4):

**Bag of Not Much Holding.**

This large bag has an interior space considerably smaller than its outside dimensions.  On attempting to place items within the bag, they do not fit.  The bag is able to hold some sandy lint but that is all.

Answer (score 3):

I give you the [Useless Box](https://www.instructables.com/Useless-Box-4/) or in DnD speak "The Box of Opening and Closing"

**The Box of Opening and Closing**

*Common Magical Item*

This box appears as a regular wooden box with a lid that appears unable to be opened. In addition there a small switch in the "Off" position on the front.

As a bonus action, the user can flip the switch to the "On" position. Upon doing so a tiny automaton will immediately open the box and flip the switch back into the "Off" position before returning into the box and closing the lid.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually tricky, because by default the most useless Item ever would necessarily be an item that is closest to not being able to provide any use at all. A cursed item might be useful if you convince (or force) an enemy to use it, an item that does something pointless can potentially be a source of entertainment, even a compass that only points to the one using it or to itself could potentially be useful in some way (even if said way is as something de to be thrown at someone or as a makeshift weapon or paperweight). Even a very small bag can still provide the user with the ability to employ [a valuable and effective defense strategy](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PTAXUYLbFYk). Based on this I present to you:

***The Etherereal Cane.***

It's literally an uncannily average looking cane, with 2 magic abilities:

1-it has a spell that makes it go completely unnoticed by anyone that's not actively trying to pay close attention to the cane specifically.

2- it becomes intangible to anything and anyone but the person holding it with their hand, and only at the point it's being handled. The cane also becomes intangible if it's thrown at someone, only becoming tangible again once it is about to touch the ground, which it does without making a single sound. If the cane isn't being held by anyone, any physical interaction, harmful or not, that isn't specifically the act of picking the cane up will result in the cane becoming ethereal to the object about to touch it.

Trying to support your body with it by using is as a normal cane? Can't do. Trying to hit someone? Nope. Trying to look fancy or ridiculous? You'll need more than just the cane, it is already so average looking it'd go unnoticed by the absolute majority of people without any effects, which is aggravated by its magical property of being almost unnoticeable to anyone that's not actually trying to remember it exists. Trying to determine how deep a hole is? The cane won't help you by making a sound. The cane's effects don't even extend to the Wearer, which would actually make it a very good item for a rogue, it's simply a magic cane that can't interact with anyone or anything but the hand of whoever is holding it and that is designed to go unnoticed.

This only potential use I can see for this item would be to make someone loose their balance, since not only is the cane worthless as a cane (meaning a first use could result in a unappreciated lesson), only one person can touch it at a time, your hand will phase through it if you try, so if someone somehow forced themselves to remain aware of the cane's existence and tried to take it, they could loose their balance as their hand phases through the cane.

If anything this cane would probably end up left in some corner of the world forgotten and unnoticed since anyone that isn't actively looking for it can't really perceive it.

Comment: "We are going to practice some sword techniques without a partner. So many people showed up that normally we wouldn't have the space but fortunately I managed to get these ethereal canes on the cheap..."